# Arduino UNO Hangs on USART0 RX ISR

Tags: c, arduino, avr, arduino-uno, atmega

I have a simple example where I configure the UART0 to interrupt on RX and TX.

The TX interrupt works great, but the RX interrupt handler hangs no matter what I put in it.

If I remove the interrupt handler then it correctly crashes. If I turn off the interrupts then it doesn't hang anymore. As soon as I turn on the interrupt and add an ISR, then it hangs when receiving a character. The watchdog then resets the device.

I examined the Arduino Core implementation and can't see anything they're doing that I'm not.

Any ideas?

```c
/* USART Interrupts */
#define USART_RX_vect       __vector_18
#define USART_UDRE_vect     __vector_19
#define USART_TX_vect       __vector_20


void usart_init_hardware(USART_CONFIG_T cfg)
{
    usart_set_mode(cfg.mode);
    usart_set_baud(cfg.baud);
    usart_set_parity(cfg.parity);
    usart_set_stop_bits(cfg.stop_bits);
    usart_set_character_size(cfg.character_size);

    if (USART_MODE_SYNCHRONOUS == cfg.mode) {
        /* This bit is used for synchronous mode only.
         * - ATmega328P Datasheet page 162 */
        usart_set_clock_polarity(cfg.clock_polarity);
    }

    /* Enable interrupts on RX and TX */
    UCSR0B.bits.RXCIEn = TRUE;
    UCSR0B.bits.TXCIEn = TRUE;
    UCSR0B.bits.UDRIEn = FALSE;

    /* Enable TX and RX */
    UCSR0B.bits.RXENn = TRUE;
    UCSR0B.bits.TXENn = TRUE;
}


ISR(USART_RX_vect)
{
    volatile U8_T c;

    /* Clear interrupt flag */
    c = UDR0.byte;
}
```

I tried removing everything from the ISR, which should cause a hang as the interrupt gets called repeatedly.

I then added the `UDR0` retrieval back into the ISR, which should cure the hang as it disables the interrupt flag.

I tried manually disabling the interrupt flag.

Nothing appears to cure the hang.

`UDR0` is a union which is mapped to `0xC6`

```c
typedef union {
    struct {
        VBOOL_T bit0 : 1;
        VBOOL_T bit1 : 1;
        VBOOL_T bit2 : 1;
        VBOOL_T bit3 : 1;
        VBOOL_T bit4 : 1;
        VBOOL_T bit5 : 1;
        VBOOL_T bit6 : 1;
        VBOOL_T bit7 : 1;
    } bits;
    VU8_T byte;
} REGISTER_T;

extern volatile REGISTER_T UDR0;
```

and

```
SECTIONS
{
  /* USART */
  UCSR0A        = 0xC0;
  UCSR0B        = 0xC1;
  UCSR0C        = 0xC2;
  UBRR0         = 0xC4;
  UDR0          = 0xC6;
  ...
```

Comment: Are you sure about that __vector_18 ? I can see 19 everywhere for USART_RX on atmega328

Comment: I got __vector_18 from AVR-LIBC/include/avr/iom328p.h line 854. I'll try 19

Comment: I can't spot the problem with your ISR so I think maybe the problem is in another part of the code.  I would suggest posting a [MCVE] for this, and include a description of the signal on the RX pin.  As much as possible, use definitions of things like `USART_RX_vect` and `UDR0` from avr-libc by including the right headers instead of redefining them yourself.  You could also dump the assembly of your ISR in your final ELF file and make sure it has `lds [some register],198` in it.

Comment: @hcheung I've written loads of code using the standard libraries. The point of this exercise is to learn how they're implemented by doing it myself, from the datasheet.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Good tip on inspecting the disassembly. Unfortunately I did find the instruction there so that wasn't the problem. I figured it out though, see the answer.

Comment: Are you using C or C++? Arduino is usually C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I defined my ISR in terms of `interrupt` instead of `signal`. I'm still researching what the implications of this difference are, but as far as I can tell, it's related to disabling global interrupts on entry.

```c
#define ISR(vect) \
    void vect(void) __attribute__((interrupt, used, externally_visible)); \
    void vect(void)
```

should have been

```
#define ISR(vect) \
    void vect(void) __attribute__((signal, used, externally_visible)); \
    void vect(void)
```

Comment: And this is exactly disadvantage of "reinventing wheel". Nobody knows you started with a square :D About numbering: in the documentation they starts with 1 for the reset vector and headers starts with 0 as an offset from reset vector

Comment: Yeah, the question didn't contain your definition of ISR so there was no hope of anyone figuring this out.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> /* USART Interrupts */
> #define USART_RX_vect       __vector_18
> #define USART_UDRE_vect     __vector_19
> #define USART_TX_vect       __vector_20
> ```

**Don't do that.**  Instead,

```cpp
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
```

This defines appropriate macros like `USART_RX_vect` and also the `ISR` macro.

Also it appears you are hacking all the info that's found in the device header, also included with `#include <avr/io.h>.

The symbols you are defining in the SECTION part of the linker script are also not the way things are done.  The values are all defined in `avr/io.h`, just use them.